# USB drives are not recognized

Tags: usb-drive

last night I tried to resolve the suspend issue in my laptop with elementary OS by installing Netext73 optimizer.

Now I am unable to use my pendrives. (The led indicator works; mouse/keyboard works but no pendrives).
On doing `sudo fdisk -l`, it recognizes the pen drive(but does not mount). The following is the output:

---

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003bda2

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968517631   484257792   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968519678   976771071     4125697    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       968519680   976771071     4125696   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.8 GB, 15804137472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1921 cylinders, total 30867456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008f5cb

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    30867455    15432704    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

---

P.S. The suspend issue still persists.

Comment: Install `disks` from software centre and select usb drive and then mount

Comment: @Ravan Tried disks, but it did not work.

Comment: please remove and connect again usb, Also [edit] Q and add output of `lsusb` before and after connecting usb @Morty

Comment: Please ask the suspend issue in a new question

Answer (score 1):

If it is exfat, you will need to install the files below.

Many sd cards seem to have this format by default (out of the box).

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse 
sudo apt install exfat-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that USB drives does not get auto-mounted in elementary OS. Moreover, if `fdisk` lists them, it means that they get recognized.